# Waiting for systemd unit to shutdown with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, systemd

I have the following systemd unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=myDaemon
Before=multi-user.target
Before=graphical.target
After=network-online.target
After=nss-lookup.target
After=tyme-sync.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/myFolder/myApp
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
SuccessExitStatus=5 6

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `/opt/myFolder/myApp` points to a daemonized cpp binary, which shutsdown gracefully when receiving SIGTERM. I want to have a bash script which calls `systemctl stop myService` and waits for it to shutdown before doing other stuff. Is there something I can set in the unit file itself, or I just need to keep checking for service status until it's not active any more?

Comment: Have you tried using a lockfile?

Comment: How would you run that bash script ?

Comment: @Philippe by running ./bashScript. Not sure I understand your question

Comment: You can write a bash script which calls `systemctl stop myService`, then keep checking `systemctl status myService`